# How to convert a Class' all String fields to uppercase

Tags: java

Hi I want to convert a class's all `String` field values to their uppercase format. How can I do this? Please help.

Example:

```
public class ConvertStringToUppercase{
    private String field1; //to be converted Uppercase
    private String field2; //to be converted Uppercase
    private String field3; //to be converted Uppercase
    ...... //more fields
}
```

Comment: Do you want to convert the field names or their values?

Comment: I want to convert field values

Comment: Put them in a collection and then give the class a method, `toUpperCase()` where you loop through the collection assigning each String its upper case representation.  Note, that reflection can solve this as well, but whenever I think "reflection" I wonder if instead do I need to re-design my program. What is the motivation behind this anyway?

Comment: Step 1: Get all the fields. Step 2: Narrow to strings. Step 3: Convert and set back. Step 4: ??? Step 5: Profit.

Comment: What's the use case of this? Why don't you adjust the value in the getter or setter?

Comment: @Thomas, I want to automatically convert all fields to prevent messy code

Comment: Exactly as @Thomas suggests: why not give the class a `getUpperCase(int fieldCount)` method where you don't change the Strings themselves but instead return an upper-case representation of them.

Comment: @mucayufa It's messier doing it the way you want to, less obvious, and more difficult to maintain.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, I want to insert related class fields to database.

Comment: What would make the code messy, the conversion to upper case or lower case values? And why would the conversion to upper case make the code messy in your opinion?

Comment: @Thomas user can see uppercase format if I do your way in my code thats getter setter, user see uppercase format in jsf 2. but i just use this when inserting to database

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels, I explained your question. You can see the answer for Thomas

Comment: If you read the data from the database and display it the user would see the upper case, too. Or would you convert it back to lower case? If so how would you preserve the characters that were entered in upper case? Again: _why_ do you need the uppercase text in the database? What's the use of that?

Comment: This work single way not multiple way. Thats user fill the blank text boxes in a form, but inserting to database, I want to convert name surname etc values to uppercase. My aim is just to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use reflection for a *quick and dirty* solution:

```
ConvertStringToUpperCase t = new ConvertStringToUpperCase();
for(Field f: t.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {            
    if(f.getType().equals(String.class)) {              
        f.setAccessible(true);
        f.set(t, ((String)f.get(t)).toUpperCase());
    }           
}
```

This is not a nice approach however, since private fields should not be modified this way.

Comment: quick and **dirty** indeed...and in practice, this is definitely not the approach to take.

Comment: How is this more efficient than doing it in the class itself?  Reflection is not cheap..

Answer (score 5):

```
public class ConvertStringToUppercase{
    private String field1; //to be converted Uppercase
    private String field2; //to be converted Uppercase
    private String field3; //to be converted Uppercase

    public void toUpperCase() {
        this.field1 = this.field1.toUpperCase();
        this.field2 = this.field2.toUpperCase();
        this.field3 = this.field3.toUpperCase();
        // ...
    }
}
```

Or, if you want immutability:

```
public class ConvertStringToUppercase{
    private String field1; //to be converted Uppercase
    private String field2; //to be converted Uppercase
    private String field3; //to be converted Uppercase

    public ConvertStringToUppercase toUpperCase() {
        return new ConvertStringToUppercase(this.field1.toUpperCase(),
                                            this.field2.toUpperCase(),
                                            this.field3.toUpperCase(),
                                            // ...);
    }
}
```

Make sure to check for null if the fields are nullable.

Comment: +1 this answer pretty much covers everything, including null checks. :D

Comment: @mre I don't see null checks :) - it's still one of the cleanest ways of doing it. (+1)

Comment: @Thomas, *Make sure to check for null if the fields are nullable.* :D

Comment: @mre yes, didn't see that .. D'oh!

Answer (score 3):

```
try {
    ConvertStringToUppercase testClass = new ConvertStringToUppercase();
    for (Field field : testClass.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
          if (field.getType().equals(String.class)) {
            if (!field.isAccessible()) 
                field.setAccessible(true);
            if (field.get(testClass) != null && ((String) field.get(testClass)).trim() != "") {                          
                field.set(testClass, ((String) field.get(testClass)).toUpperCase());
            }
          }  
    }
} catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using reflection but it will be ugly and slow.
Use `ConvertStringToUppercase.class.getDeclaredFields()` to get `Field` objects. Then use `field.getType() == String.class` to determine when field is of String type.

Then use `field.get(this)` to get the string, uppercase it, then use `field.set(this, upperCaseString)` to set the field to the new value.

Comment: you can cache list of Field objects of string type to skip first two steps when doing multiple invocations.